# How to send image file to google cloud functions via curl and read with python?

Tags: python, image, function, curl, cloud

I want to send an image.png file via curl to google cloud functions and make a keras-model prediction on it. (the model is not specified here..)

I have looked through various of Threads but no one fits to my problem exactly. (like this one: [How to use curl to send file to Google Cloud Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429665/how-to-use-curl-to-send-file-to-google-cloud-function)  I dont want to save the file on cloud storage... ) The crucial part is to obtain the "image" instance from the "request" object given in the python environment on google cloud functions.

```
# the request instance is automatically created by google cloud functions 
# in advance


def print_prediction(request): 


  result = 'Hello, you are looking good today!'

  if request.method == 'POST':  

    image_raw = [request.form.get('image')]

    result = 'show me whats in there'... + str(request) + str(image_raw) 


  return result
```

When I pass my image file via the following command, I expect the "request" variable (which passed automatically given in google cloud functions from the request into the python environment) to have properties like "image" that I can extract by request.form.get().

curl --form 'image=@path_to_image/some_image.png' https://provided-url-from-cloud-functions

To understand which attributes the request object has, I tried various prints of the objects but I cant help myself.

The output of the function above after executing the curl command is:

'show me whats in there http://europe-west1-chris-weather-app-1.cloudfunctions.net/' [POST]>[None]'

So I think I did not extract anything from the request at all. When I use vars(request) as output it also doesnt help.